# Le mot « Manne » peut-il traduire « Godsend » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, usage

[**Godsend**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/godsend) :  *a desirable or needed thing or event that comes unexpectedly*

> The widespread rain was a godsend for farmers.

Le mot **manne** peut-il traduire en français le sens de **Godsend** dans ce contexte ? Est-ce un mot courant ? A-t-il toujours une connotation religieuse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans le terme « godsend » et « manna from Heaven » on retrouve sans aucune différence l'idée de « fourni providentiellement » ; il y a cependant une différence importante ; dans le premier terme il n'est question que de cela, alors que dans le second on doit reconnaitre en supplément l'idée d'abondance, de fourniture continue.

En conséquence, « manne » traduit « manna » ;

- Les avantages nous étaient donnés en abondance, tels une manne !
  *Benefits were thrown in plenty upon us, a true manna from Heaven.*

Si cet élément d'abondance est absent on doit utiliser autre chose, soit une périphrase avec « venu(e)(s)(es) du ciel » soit l'expression « don du ciel », lesquelles conviennent bien comme ce qui vient du ciel  vient de Dieu ; c'est donc, tout au moins dans ce cas, providentiel.

> (TLFi) B. P. méton. Dieu, la Providence ou tout principe de transcendance

- Thanks to that  solution, a true godsend, we were able to get out of the desert.
  1- *Grâce à cette solution, une vraie **aubaine  venue du ciel**, nous avons pu sortir du désert.*
  2- *Grâce à cette solution, un véritable **don du ciel**, nous avons pu sortir du désert.*

Non, on ne peut pas traduire « godsend » par « manne », on change le concept ; le mot « manne » est assez courant : on le trouve dans toutes sortes de contextes.

Dire que ce mot n'a pas de connotations religieuses n'est pas tout à fait exact. Voici la définition du TLFi ;

> A. 1. [P. allus. à la Bible] Nourriture providentielle que Dieu envoya aux Hébreux pendant la traversée du désert.

On l'emploie en « faisant allusion à la Bible », c'est à dire que l'on compte, tout au moins de façon idéale, comme les références culturelles tendent à se perdre ou ne sont jamais acquises, sur le fait que l'interlocuteur connaisse l'histoire biblique de la manne et ainsi ait un moyen de comparaison dans le sens d'évaluer la situation qui est la matière du discours ; il n'est nul besoin d'être un croyant pour se permettre cet usage allusif, mais lorsqu'on y a recours, on émet immanquablement des connotations sur le plan de la considération de ce qui est providentiel, de ce qui est sans autre explication que celle d'un fait auquel l'être humain ne prend pas part, qu'il ne contrôle pas ; si l'on s'en remet à la définition du mot « Providence »,

> « Puissance supérieure, divine, qui gouverne le monde, qui veille sur le destin des individus. » (TLFi),

on voit que même sans croire en une divinité quelconque de façon « authentique », on évoque la puissance des dieux en général. On pourrait dire qu'il n'a pas de connotations religieuses effectives en cela qu'un enseignement religieux quelconque serait  insinué, ou même que l'existence d'un dieu quelconque serait par là entendue, ce n'est pas le cas. Il y a un enseignement certain que, nous les utilisateurs laïques du terme se doivent de comprendre, et cela c'est que l'ecclésiastique  ne colorera pas son langage avec de telles allusions qui pour lui/elle resteront profanes, et en cela nous avons un autre indice pour affirmer que le terme n'est pas utilisé avec de véritables connotations religieuses.

Answer (score 2):

*Manne* n'a pas la connotation religieuse évidente de *godsend*, et est plutôt utilisé pour désigner une ressource financière (on précise d'ailleurs souvent *une manne financière*).

> Les subventions de la politique agricole commune représentent une manne financière importante pour le secteur agricole.

Pour garder une connotation religieuse assez similaire, on peut utiliser le nom *bénédiction* au sens figuré, avec une petite touche d'exagération qui peut être ironique.

> Les pluies abondantes furent une bénédiction pour les agriculteurs.

Comment: Ou peut-être don du ciel ?

Comment: Oui, pourquoi pas ? Voire même *miracle* si l'événement était complètement inattendu et providentiel.

Comment: C'est noté ! Merci encore.

Answer (score 2):

C'est un mot que je n'ai quasiment jamais vu (dans ce sens-là). Wordreference recommande :

> aubaine, chance
>
> (*familier*)    bénédiction

Je ne suis pas d'accord avec le fait de qualifier *bénédiction* de familier. Il n'a pas son sens littéral (peu de connotation religieuse ou spirituelle), mais il est approprié pour tous les registres et c'est la traduction que je choisirais.

*Aubaine* et *chance* sont un peu trop faibles à mon goût. Ils décrivent quelque chose de positif, mais pas forcément indispensable.

Dire :

> La pluie torrentielle a été une bénédiction pour les agriculteurs

sous-entend que la situation aurait été extrêmement difficile sans, et que c'était inespéré. À mon sens c'est plus proche du sens de "*godsend*".